# MongoDB: Replace entire array if it exists Or create new if it doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb

If i have collection full of arrays like below,

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51f21c47564f4a9f411baf8d"),
        "Gender" : [
                {
                        "key" : "m",
                        "desc" : "male"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51f21c9a564f4a9f411baf8e"),
        "marital status" : [
                {
                        "key" : "m",
                        "desc" : "married"
                },
                {
                        "key" : "s",
                        "desc" : "single"
                }
        ]
}
```

what is the query to replace entire array if it exists and create new if doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Syntax:**

```
db.collection.update({<key>: {'$exists': true}}, {<key>: <value>}, 
{upsert: true});
```

**Query For Above Scenario**

```
db.collection.update({"Gender": {'$exists': true}}, {"Gender": 
[{"key": "m", "desc": "male"}, {"key": "f", "desc": "female"}]}, true);
```